# Prevent cross-site scripting from url

Tags: html, apache, http, jsp

How to prevent xss attack from this tag in my website:
<%=request.getParameter("errorMsg")%>
as this is rendering user input via url in error page
above code snippet is present in a error.jsp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the JSP expression

```
<%= request.getParameter("errorMsg") %>
```

with the JSTL tag `c:out` as

```
<c:out value="${param.errorMsg}" />
```

This will prevent cross-site scripting attacks by escaping any `<html>` markup injected in the *request parameter* through replacement of special characters, like `<`, `>`, with their equivalent *HTML entities* `&lt;`, `&gt;`, etc.

Make sure to add the JSTL core tag library to your `error.jsp` using the `taglib` directive as

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

---

***Edit:** (in response to OP's comment)*

Your code has a bug, it will throw a `NullPointerException` because `encodedValue` is `null`.

Replace it with the *static* method `URLEncoder.encode(request.getParameter("errorMsg"), "UTF-8")` instead. Then make sure `ErrorHTTPSession.jsp` too uses the `c:out` tag to print this `errorMsg` and you should be good then.

Comment: Ravi K Thapliyal, there is this code part also present on the same JSP file <%if (dctmAccessorObj.getCurrentSession() == null) { System.out.println("Inside IF Session");  java.net.URLEncoder encodedValue = null; response.sendRedirect("/ErrorHTTPSession.jsp?errorMsg=" + encodedValue.encode(request.getParameter("errorMsg")));%>. Should any change require in this also?

Comment: Ravi K Thapliyal thanks, it really helped.